# How to extract an integer number in a string, within a specific characters ?

Tags: java

I want to get an integer number, in a string, in Java. The string is:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.gazzetta.it/calcio/fantanews/statistiche/serie-a-2014-15/andrea_pirlo_669">Pirlo A.</a>
```

I want to get the value "669", which is between _ and ". I know it is possible to use StringTokenizer, but the code I write is not so good. Is there any simpler solution to do that ?

Comment: *"but the code I write is not so good."* And how does this code look like? Please post it and tell us why you think it isn't good.

Comment: Are you using a html parser?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the JSoup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve it with regular expressions, using Pattern and Matcher classes. Here's an example:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*_(\\d{3})\".*");

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    final String input = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.gazzetta.it/calcio/fantanews/statistiche/serie-a-2014-15/andrea_pirlo_669\">Pirlo A.</a>";
    final Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(input);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    } else {
        System.out.println("No match");
    }
}
```

The regular expression is `.*_(\\d{3})\".*`:

`.*` -> Any number (including 0) of any characters

`_` -> Character `_`

`(\\d{3})` -> 3 digits. The parenthesis tells the regex engine to keep this match as a group, which will refer to it later as group 1 (`m.group(1)`)

`\"` -> Double quote character

`.*` -> Any number (including 0) of any characters

Comment: I would replace `\\d{3}` by `\\d+` to find numbers of variable length.

Comment: Thanks for describing regular pattern :)

Comment: @Jan That was my first idea but he asked specifically for that string and that number. If he said "for example",  I would have used `+`

Answer (score 1):

This code works:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*_(\\d+)\".*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(<yourstringhere>);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

To understand it, have a look at regular expressions, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

Or you cant use [String split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method (It will returns splitted string as array by regex in param)

1. split by `">`
2. first result of 1. split by `_`
3. number will be last item in result array (`array[array.length-1]`)

:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Jsoup:

```
public void extractNumber()
{
    String s = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.gazzetta.it/calcio/fantanews/statistiche/serie-a-2014-15/andrea_pirlo_669\">Pirlo A.</a>";
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(s);
    System.out.println(document);
    Elements elementsByTag = document.getElementsByTag("a");
    String attr = elementsByTag.attr("href");
    System.out.println(attr);
    String sNumber = attr.substring(attr.lastIndexOf('_')+1);
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(sNumber));
}
```

Note that `elementsByTag` is a collection, you may want to iterate and do for every `<a />`'s `href` attribute

Comment: A very good solution ! I have to modify something, because more string s, are present in a div. Thank you